# pragma omp for/parallel not working?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this code

```
#define N 2048
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1=fopen("myfile.txt", "a");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int *x=malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
            int *xtemp=malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
            int (*adj)[N];
            adj=malloc(sizeof *adj *N);
            ...//other declarations
            #pragma omp for
            for(int k=0;k<100;k++)
            {
                /* do things involving x,xtemp, adj...*/
            }
            fprintf(fp1,"things \n");
            ... //free vectors part...
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to run fine, but when I check with `htop` the usage of my cpu (i3 dual core with hyper-threading), I see that only one thread is working at 100%.

So I put some `printf` in my code to see how many times I would get the same writing on my terminal, like, after :

```
#pragma omp parallel
 {
   printf("Hey, I'm inside the par zone!\n"); 
    .... 
 }
```

but it seems that I get only one `printf` per time, so I think that only one core is working. I tried the same thing after the `pragma omp for` part but still get the same issue.

Why it seems that `pragma omp parallel` is not parallelizing anything? I tried a simpler program  (a simple parallelized version of hello world!) and it works, I get as many stamps as my core numbers.

I tried to put all together in a `#pragma omp parallel for` loop but I get a segmentation fault - core dumped error...

...........................

[Here](http://textuploader.com/d5lyi) it is my MCVE code, it gives the same problem.  (Sorry for the indents, but the file uploader screwed up things).
The functions before main just make some calculations, using rand(), nothing special.

my compilation line is:`gcc -w -std=c99 MC.c -o try  -lm -fopenmp -lquadmath -O3`

Comment: Did you compile with an OpenMP-enabling compiler switch? For example, GCC requires `-fopenmp` to use the OpenMP pragmas. Likewise, did you set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to any value prior to  running your code?

Comment: Yes I compiled with -fopenmp and I didn't set OMP_NUM_THREADS

Comment: Could you please give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) exemplifying your issue, along with your compilation command line and execution command?

Comment: Sure, I need some time though... Just a question, do I have to edit my post or post an answer?

Comment: Edit the post. Answers are for answers ;)

Comment: I uploaded a simpler code which gives me the same issue, but unfortunately the text uploader screwed up a lot :(.

Comment: Calls to `rand()` do not work well with parallelism since `rand()` keeps a global state internally. There is probably a mutex or something similar there killing your parallelism. Try using `rand_r()` rather... (using RNG in parallel is a whole topic in itself so I just won't tell more now)

Comment: Ok but how could it affect the number of parallelized threads?  I will give it a try in a couple of hours and let you know. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ok I changed rand to rand_r but still the same problem, only one core is working...

Comment: Write to a buffer in parallel then write the buffer to a file with one thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues which I can see:

- Use of a global random number generator in parallel. That is a whole world of issues in itself, but a quick fix could be to either use a per-thread RND like `rand_r()` instead of the global `rand()`, or to protect the calls to `rand()` with a `#pragma omp critical RNG` (which is likely to be a performance killer). In any case, `rand()` is not suited for serious work.
- The attempt to close your output file in a parallel region.

Now, the reason why the parallelism doesn't work is that you wrote `#pragma omp shared(mfield) parallel` instead of `#pragma omp parallel shared(mfield)`.
Once this fixed, the code spawns threads as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Oh my god I can't believe I've lost all the day trying to figure out the error.

Comment: But how this isn't an issue for the compiler? He didn't even warn me about it. How does it interpret `#pragma omp shared(mfield) parallel`?

Comment: From gcc's man page: "-w Inhibit all warning messages.". Just try compiling with `-Wall` and you get "mcve.c:130:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp shared [-Wunknown-pragmas]"

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem related to the fprintf part of the code. If I parallelize only the k-loop things work just fine. 
[OpenMP and File I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577144/openmp-and-file-i-o) apparently says the same.